# Skip specific database during specific hours

Tags: sql-server, database, skip, hour

I use T-SQL scripts for monitoring a SQL Server.
For the one which check if database are online, I have a problem : every night, I restore one database now so I get an alert between 04:05 and 04:15.
I would like to modify my script in order to check all databases during 24 hours except for the one during the time I restore it.

This is my query to check if database are not online :

```
SELECT name
FROM master.sys.databases
WHERE state_desc <> 'ONLINE'
```

When I try that :

```
SELECT name
FROM master.sys.databases
WHERE state_desc <> 'ONLINE'
AND DATEPART (HOUR, GETDATE ()) = 04
AND DATEPART (MINUTE, GETDATE ()) BETWEEN 05 AND 15
AND name <> 'TEST'
```

I'm blind for others hours.

And with that :

```
SELECT name
FROM master.sys.databases
WHERE state_desc <> 'ONLINE'
OR state_desc <> 'ONLINE'
AND DATEPART (HOUR, GETDATE ()) = 04
AND DATEPART (MINUTE, GETDATE ()) BETWEEN 05 AND 15
AND name <> 'TEST'
```

I can still see my database not online.

I'm not far from the solution but I'm stucked.
Someone can provide me some help please ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the idea behind `WHERE state_desc <> 'ONLINE' OR state_desc <> 'ONLINE' ` ?

Comment: The whole part is `OR state_desc <> 'ONLINE' AND DATEPART (HOUR, GETDATE ()) = 04 AND DATEPART (MINUTE, GETDATE ()) BETWEEN 05 AND 15 AND name <> 'TEST'` and the idea is to avoid showing all databases except TEST database

Comment: @Thalyn SQL Server does not really respect the order of operations as other languages would, so you should always wrap complementary criteria within parentheses, as per my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to be a bit more specific in your `where` clause to make sure that you are applying exactly the criteria you want to:

```
select [name]
from master.sys.databases
where state_desc <> 'ONLINE'    -- Only return the database when it is not online
    and ([name] <> 'TEST'       -- when either it isn't the TEST database
         or (cast(getdate() as time) < '04:05'      -- or we are outside the TEST
             or cast(getdate() as time) >= '04:15'  -- database restore window
            )
        )
```

What this will do is return all databases that have a `state_desc` that isn't `ONLINE` for the period outside of `04:05` to `04:15`, but only those that don't have a `name` of `TEST` within that period.